# GetListItems return undefined if query applied

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, jquery, spservices

I'm using GetListItems with query on SP page called for eg. "A" and everything is working there. Now I copied same code to second list B and in this list **xData.responseXML** is empty when I'm using CAMLQuery (order by query). But if I'm not using it, response I get is ok.

```
   completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      console.log("is working here")
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() { 
          console.log("but not working here")
```

Can you tell me why? Why some CAMLQuery is prventing to get me responseXML? And why its working on diffrent webpage? How it is possible?

EDIT: function added

I'm running it by

```
 getDefaultView()
```

and the function is:

```
    var getDefaultView = function(search_id){
    var list = "Projects";   //list name
    var method = "GetListItems";
    var fieldsToRead = "<ViewFields>" +
        "<FieldRef Name='ID' />" +
        "<FieldRef Name='ProjectCode' />" +
        "</ViewFields>";
    var query = "<OrderBy>" +
        "<FieldRef Name='ProjectCode'/>" +
        "</OrderBy>";
    if(search_id!=undefined){
        query = "<Query>" +
            "<Where>"+
            "<Eq>"+
            "<FieldRef Name = 'ID' /><Value Type='Text'>" + search_id +"</Value>"+
            "</Eq>"+
            "</Where>" +
            "</Query>";
    }
    $().SPServices({
        operation: method,
        async: false, 
        listName: list,
        CAMLQuery: query, //if commented everything works
        CAMLViewFields: fieldsToRead,

        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            console.log(xData); //here the response is displayed properly.
            console.log("is executing");
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                console.log("is not executing");
            });

        }
    });
};
```

And summarry:

1. **xData** is full of data I asked. Both when using CAMLQuery query,and when not using query.
2. Code below is executing only when CAMLQuery is commented

   $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
     console.log("is not executing");
   });

EDIT2:

POST message:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
<listName>Projects</listName>
<viewName></viewName>
<query>
<Query>
<OrderBy>
<FieldRef Name="ID"></FieldRef>
</OrderBy>
</Query>
</query>
<viewFields>
<ViewFields>
<FieldRef Name="ID"></FieldRef>
<FieldRef Name="ProjectCode"></FieldRef>
</ViewFields>
</viewFields>
<rowLimit>0</rowLimit>
<queryOptions>
<QueryOptions></QueryOptions>
</queryOptions>
</GetListItems>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And returned XML:

```
XML Parsing Error: reference to invalid character number Location: moz-nullprincipal:{c4f4a895-d0bb-45fc-b562-6de85f249fa5} Line Number 11642, Column 225:

...itle='Salesforce effectiveness operations toolkit&#11;' tag_ID='11407' tag_Un...
...-------------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: We need to see your CAML, and are you certain the field you are ordering by exists with the same internal name in this other list?

Comment: updated Eric. What do you think about it?

Comment: anyone? Please help :/

Comment: Again, are you sure the ProjectCode field exists in this other list and has the same internal name?

Comment: Eric - it was working with different list. Now I switched to "Projects", its working as it should but I'm not receiving  "xData.responseXML".

But the "xData" is full of data I requested. 

Added post msg in topic.

Comment: OK, i found it. The issue was that "&#11;" sign. The problem is that there is a lot of them in SP. Is there a way to parse it even with this sign?

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by function below:

```
   completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            //alert(xData);
           // console.log(xData.responseText);
            var specialCharsDeleted = xData.responseText.replace(/&#11;/g, '');
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( specialCharsDeleted );
            $(xmlDoc).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                console.log("its working");
}
```

so basicly SP was responsing with weird characers, I deleted them from text and converted again to xml.